# Apply majority voting to a Numpy (key, value) array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array where the first column is an ID and the second column a classification. I would like to apply majority voting so that each ID has only 1 classification. When the the frequency of classification is 50-50, I'd like to pick a classification randomly.

My array looks like this:

```
>>> print(myArray)
array([
[10, 0],
[10, 1],
[101, 0],
[101, 0],
[101, 2],
[102, 0],
[102, 0],
[103, 0],
[103, 1],
[103, 1]])
```

I want it to become this (based on majority voting)

```
>>> print(myArray)
array([
[10, 0],
[101, 0],
[102, 0],
[103, 1]])
```

or

```
>>> print(myArray)
array([
[10, 1],
[101, 0],
[102, 0],
[103, 1]])
```

Comment: Use pandas. What you want can be simply made with a `groupby` operation.

Comment: @alkasm can you give this example?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to convert the numpy array into a defaultdict and then convert back to numpy array

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: arr = np.array([[10, 0], [10, 1], [10, 1]])

In [4]: arr
Out[4]:
array([[10,  0],
       [10,  1],
       [10,  1]])

In [11]: darr = defaultdict(list)

In [12]: for item in arr:
    ...:     a,b = item
    ...:     darr[a].append(b)
    ...:

In [13]: darr
Out[13]: defaultdict(list, {10: [0, 1, 1]})
```

So after converting to default dict, you can iterate the dict and choose whatever value you need for each key.

Comment: FYI you can just iterate over the pairs directly: `for a, b in arr:`